# Modifing Alfresco 5.0.d Add-ons

Tags: maven, alfresco, alfresco-share

I've been trying to modify an addon to accept filtering in custom datalists.

The addon is called DatalistExtensions for Alfresco Share and can be found at https://github.com/deas/contentreich-alfresco-datalists This is supposed to be working on the version 5.*

It comes with an example. That example doesn't work at all, it gives multiple errors... I fixed the errors but it still doesn't work.

The full explanation of the behaviour can be found here: 
https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/filters-custom-datalists-07052016-1320

Now the problem:

I decided to modify the add-on itself. My test was easy, I found where the filter form is created which is inside the file: contentreich-extdl.xml that is found on contentreich-alfresco-datalists-master/contentreich-extdl-share/src/main/resources/alfresco/site-data/extension/

It didn't work at all... Since it was too strange to me I decided to delete one of the built-in filters and it was still working as always which just killed my mind.

The steps I did:

- Added the lines into the file.
- Ran the mvn package after the change.
- Copied the target files created.

What am I missing to make this changes work?

Comment: First of all call following url: http://localhost:8080/share/service/modules/deploy and look whether your extension modules are deplyoed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the changes I was doing were not reflected, in order to archive that you must first clean your maven target and then build the package.

```
mvn clean
mvn package
```

or even

```
mvn clean package
```

Hope this helps other people!